# BeautifulSoup to get image name from P class picture tag in Python

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

The HTML looks

```
<p class="rating item-rating">
<picture>
<source srcset="/assets/img/ratings/rating-4_5.svg" type="image/svg+xml"/>
<img src="/assets/img/ratings/rating-4_5.png"/>
</picture>
<span>
260
</span>
</p>
```

And I would like to get

```
/assets/img/ratings/rating-4_5.png
```

How should I improve the following code?

```
img = soup.findAll('p',attrs={'class':'rating item-rating'})

for i in img:
    print(i.picture)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to get to the `img` tag as that seems to hold the information you want in the `src` attribute.

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

s = '''<p class="rating item-rating">
<picture>
<source srcset="/assets/img/ratings/rating-4_5.svg" type="image/svg+xml"/>
<img src="/assets/img/ratings/rating-4_5.png"/>
</picture>
<span>
260
</span>
</p>'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(s, 'html.parser')
for p in soup.select('p.rating'):
    print(p.picture.img['src'])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get `src` value in `img` tag easily like :

```
   import requests

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
r = """<p class="rating item-rating">
<picture>
<source srcset="/assets/img/ratings/rating-4_5.svg" type="image/svg+xml"/>
<img src="/assets/img/ratings/rating-4_5.png"/>
</picture>
<span>
260
</span>
</p>"""
source = BeautifulSoup(r,'html')

img = source.findAll('p',attrs={'class':'rating item-rating'})

for parsing in img:
    print(parsing.img['src'])
```